# apt-get install caused all packages to be removed

Tags: apt, package-management

I am very upset by this, and I simply cannot understand WHY it happened. The reason why I am so upset is because I have people which use my Teamspeak server, and I am currently away on vacation, thus I don't have physical access to the computer.

Anyhow, I was trying to set up a IKE2 VPN, and I was trying to install Openswan.
My server is running Kodibuntu (media center ubuntu distro), and I used SSH to access it. As I was trying to install Openswan, I got a messae

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openswan : Depends: iproute
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I figured I'd just install `iproute` (bear in mind, I am not a Linux pro in any way.)

I proceed to type in,

```
sudo apt-get install iproute
```

, hoping it would fix the problem.

And I was prompted with the usual message;

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

And I quickly hit `Y` along with enter, only to realize that I just started uninstalling all the required packages on my system, and scrolling back up in Putty I find:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cupsddk iproute libatm1 libdb5.1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 138 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,172 kB of archives.
After this operation, 685 MB disk space will be freed.
```

And a few of the packages removed were:

```
- ubuntu-minimal 
- network-manager 
- network-manager-gnome
- kodibuntu-core
- openssh-server
```

Now I am wondering; how could this possibly happen? -- Why would it decide to remove all those packages?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb attr bcrelay crda dconf-cli dkms dnsmasq-base
  dpkg-repack enchant evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-desktop3-data gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-themes-standard
  gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-user-guide gsettings-ubuntu-schemas
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x hunspell-en-us hwdata ibus ibus-gtk
  ibus-gtk3 im-config indicator-application indicator-keyboard iptables
  iputils-arping iw lib32gcc1 libaa1 libaccounts-glib0 libaccountsservice0
  libaio1 libappindicator3-1 libavahi-compat-libdnssd1 libavc1394-0 libc6-i386
  libcaca0 libcamel-1.2-45 libcuda1-304 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libdebian-installer4 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14
  libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libelfg0 libenchant1c2a libfs6
  libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgeoclue0 libglamor0 libglib2.0-bin
  libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libhdb9-heimdal
  libhunspell-1.3-0 libibus-1.0-5 libical1 libiceutil35 libido3-0.1-0
  libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libkdc2-heimdal liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmm-glib0
  libmnl0 libmtdev1 libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnfnetlink0 libnl-3-200
  libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4
  libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 liboauth0 libpackagekit-glib2-16
  libprotobuf8 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtdbus4
  libreadline5 librest-0.7-0 libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsignon-glib1
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libtimezonemap1 libupower-glib1 liburl-dispatcher1
  libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxatracker2 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxvmc1
  libyelp0 libzeroc-ice35 lightdm-gtk-greeter linux-headers-generic
  lubuntu-icon-theme mobile-broadband-provider-info nautilus-data
  nvidia-libopencl1-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304 obexd-client python-dnspython
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo python3-icu
  python3-pam python3-xkit qdbus qtchooser qtcore4-l10n rdate
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules sbsigntool tdb-tools
  ttf-ubuntu-font-family ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork unity-greeter usbutils
  wireless-regdb x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils
  xfonts-base xfonts-scalable xinit xinput xserver-common yelp yelp-xsl zenity
  zenity-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cupsddk libatm1 libdb5.1
Suggested packages:
  iproute-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  accountsservice alsa-base aptdaemon avahi-daemon bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups
  colord console-setup consolekit cron cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cups
  cups-core-drivers cups-daemon dbus dbus-x11 dmraid dmsetup eject gconf2 gcr
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-keyring gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-user-share grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse hplip ifupdown
  indicator-datetime indicator-power indicator-session initramfs-tools
  initscripts iproute2 isc-dhcp-client kbd kodibuntu-core
  kodibuntu-default-session kodibuntu-default-settings kodibuntu-initscripts
  kodibuntu-live-settings kpartx kpartx-boot language-selector-common
  libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 liblvm2app2.2 libnss-mdns libpam-systemd
  libparted0debian1 lightdm linux-generic linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic linux-image-generic lubuntu-core
  lubuntu-default-settings lvm2 lxsession lxsession-logout mountall
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome nfs-common nvidia-304 nvidia-current
  nvidia-settings openssh-server parted plymouth plymouth-label
  plymouth-theme-kodibuntu-animated-logo plymouth-theme-kodibuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-kodibuntu-text plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text plymouth-x11 policykit-1 ppp pptp-linux
  printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-splix procps resolvconf rpcbind rsyslog samba
  screen-resolution-extra systemd-services ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal udev udisks udisks2
  unity-settings-daemon upower upstart ureadahead watershed wpasupplicant xorg
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-r128
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cupsddk iproute libatm1 libdb5.1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 138 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,172 kB of archives.
After this operation, 685 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: This question might be flagged for closure since this distro isn't supported on this forum. You should either try any support forums they have or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,  Could you edit the question and add output of `apt-cache policy iproute  iproute2`

Comment: @saiarcot895 -- It's practically Ubuntu, but Kodi is highly integrated; the backbone of the system is Ubuntu, so I don't see why it should be flagged for closure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this distro of Ubuntu... However, you could take a peek at the .bash_history(sp?) for any other people that may have rights to make changes to your server. Another option if you input 'N' at the very last is to try and run apt-get -f install and see if that doesn't help. That command 'should' fix your broken packages problem.

Comment: I would just like to say that I cannot access the machine atm. -- Again, OpenSSH was uninstalled, so I am just looking for a reason as to why this happened.

Comment: unfortunately, wont know until you get back at the console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with when you isntalled iproute. The only time that massive packages get removed like this from my experience is when you remove packages that are linked to meta packages. For example if you remove Evolution, it likes to remove a whole bunch of gnome stuff since the gnome stuff were dependencies for Evolution and by removing it you told the package manager that you no longer needed those dependencies.

The only way you are going to be able to troubleshoot this is with access to the machine. I think looking through the bash history would be a good place to start. Look for other packages that were removed previously.

Also, when you saw this message:

`0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 138 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

You should have stopped immediately and began troubleshooting. Apt is telling you that it is about to remove 138 packages, apt means it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. As I said; I haven't used Linux much, but when I have, I have always been used to immediately just hit "Y" and enter, because I have never had any problems like these. I know that I should read more carefully what I am continuing with, and I will keep that in mind from now on..

Comment: No problem, I know this sucks but I think the silver lining is that in the future you will know to be more careful.

Comment: Exactly, that's what this experience will teach me :)

Answer (score 0):

- I don't agree with levlaz's answer, when meta packages are removed, related packages are listed in *`automatically installed and are no longer required`* list. APT will not force you remove them, only if you run explicitly `apt-get autoremove` to remove them.
- AFAIK, It looks like a package version or a package architecture conflict:

  ```
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    cupsddk iproute libatm1 libdb5.1
  ```

  Looking for similar ones in the packages which will be *REMOVED*, I see only `iproute2`. (note: if it was a package architecture conflict, we will find same package name ex:`iproute` in to be *REMOVED* list, this wasn't the case)

  Well, that shouldn't happen. As in trusty and later releases, `iproute` is a *transitional dummy package for iproute2* :

  > This is a transitional dummy package to get upgrading systems to install
  >   the iproute2 package. It can safely be removed once no other package
  >   depends on it.

  See [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=iproute) the `iproute`/`iproute2` packages for current Ubuntu releases.
- Possibly, you got an old/bad `iproute` release from a PPA. See control file of iproute2

  ```
  Package: iproute2
  Version: 3.12.0-2
  Architecture: amd64
  ...
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libdb5.3
  Recommends: libatm1 (>= 2.4.1-17~), libxtables10
  Suggests: iproute2-doc
  Conflicts: arpd, iproute (<< 20130000-1)
  Replaces: iproute
  ```

  Check `apt-cache policy iproute iproute2`

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it when I get back on the machine.